# How to return cell number in cell label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell, and in it i have two labels side by side. the one is editable. But the other one i want repopulated with the actual row number of the cell...

Is this possible at all? where would i add the code to perform the calculation?

Comment: haha im facing the same problem!

Comment: let me know if you solve it before i do OK? thx matey!

Comment: yeah, i have to solve something else before, ill better just wait for an answer here!

Comment: @Maxner & Trev Are you guys taking the same class?

Comment: no I'm in south africa, only class we all sharing is university of hard knocks.

Comment: lol i misunderstood it, i wan't even facing that problem, im not taking any class, and i already knew that, I just read editable and calculation, so I thought it was the same prob that i have ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cellForRowAtIndex method set the label's text variable to the indexPath.row.

```
someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
```

However, if you are using a UITableView subclass, make sure that you have made the NSObject subclass of it first with a property of someLabel.

Comment: Thanks thats awesome, where do i declare indexPath?

Comment: It's in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so the indexPath variable is already declared.

Comment: Thank you very much XcodeDev, slowly but surely i will conquer Xcode!